# CSS text setting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is my code [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rttmY/). I have three text fields. headline1Txt, headline2Txt and headline3Txt. Right now it is working fine but if i change my headline1Txt to Vintage Lace Turquoise Dress. headline2Txt to SAle Price $135 and headline3Txt to Reg:$50 then my text allignment is overlapping each other and i want my text to appear like [this](http://i.share.pho.to/d1bf427d_o.jpeg) 
.
Can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong here?

```
 <div id="mainContainer">
 <div id="logo">
  <img id="Img1" src="http://i.share.pho.to/cc9794da_o.png" width="50px" height="50px"/>
 </div>
    <div id="images">
        <img id="introImg" src="http://i.share.pho.to/ebe3afc7_o.png"/>
    </div>

    <div id="headlineText">
        <p id="headline1Txt" >Striped Bag</p><br />
        <p id="headline2Txt" >$14</p><br />
        <p id="headline3Txt" >Sale $25</p><br />
    </div>
    <div id="ctaBtn">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">SHOP NOW</button>
    </div>

</div>
Thanks
```

Comment: why do you have both br and p?

Comment: well i am in my learning stage and quite new to css/jquery. May be i have not used the best approach to make it done but thats how i was able to work it out. I used br for link break

Comment: and p is used for three text fields

Comment: You should define different style block for each "HeadlineText" especial HeadLineText1.

Comment: thanks can you give me an example of what to do define in HeadLineText1

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rttmY/8/

Comment: The problem is the when you use absolute positioning, you can't cater for re-positioning when the text flows onto a new line.  I would remove all absolute positioning.

Comment: all absolute positioning from HeadlineText?

Comment: @Shanimal thanks but it has alot of line space in between

Comment: i wasn't going for pixel perfect :) but you'll definitely need separate styles for the three different text styles

Comment: How much are you attatched to the HTML as is? It could be greatly simplified. I notice in your demo some jQuery, I'm guessing that is there for a reason?

Comment: btw, not a bad attempt if you're really just learning...

Comment: thanks guys yes i am learning front end development and i am more comfortable with back end but i have a new job and they want me to convert these flash templates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The css can certainly be cleaned up. I would try to avoid using absolute positioning as much as possible because it is not as easy to maintain or make changes. In your example increasing the text length of the headlines does not shift the other headlines down, because they are absolutely positioned to stay where they are.

I tried to leave as much of your code as intact as possible and I only made changes to the css:
http://jsfiddle.net/fAsNt/

The main thing I changed was the positioning of the headlines and added a width so they wouldn't overlap with the image:

```
#headline1Txt, #headline2Txt, #headline3Txt
{
  position: relative;
  margin: 0px 2px;
  left: -150px;
  width: 170px;
  line-height: 1;
}
```

Comment: @user3718016 remove the `<br/>` tags and set a margin on the `<p>`.  [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidpauljunior/fAsNt/1/)

Comment: @user3718016 Position releative and absolute can be a little confusing for those starting out. Here are a couple of good articles to help get your head around it: http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/, http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/

Answer (score 0):

In each of your 3 headline text boxes, you specify "position: absolute;" but do not specify the "top:" property. Specify "top" where they should be and you'll be fixed right up.

Here's the js fiddle- note I added "top" at the end of your CSS:
http://jsfiddle.net/rttmY/7/

```
 #headline1Txt { top: 0; }
 #headline2Txt { top: 25px; }
 #headline3Txt { top: 50px; }
```

Also, get rid of those <br />. Since you are positioning absolute, I would also recommend using <div> tags rather than <p> tags because you're technically not making paragraphs, you are positioning blocks. The result would actually be the same, but it's a best practice to use  for absolutely positioned blocks.

Comment: that one is fine but headline1Txt  is going on top of my image

Comment: to be quite honest, this is an ad, so you either need to make your text shorter or absolutely position the box and set the height and width. 
http://jsfiddle.net/rttmY/11/

Or, switch over to relative positioning.

Comment: thanks guys this one is perfect and if i change my image like this http://jsfiddle.net/rttmY/13/ . Then it is having problems as well

Comment: if this one helped you answer your issue, would you mind clicking the checkbox for me? :)